# Is it good to use mean value theorem in $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity proofs?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question, continuity, proof-writing

I wanted to prove $f(x) = \cos(x)$ is continuous using $\epsilon-\delta$ proof

Couple of posts on MSE appealed to MVT to resolve this problem.

Namely:

> $\exists c \in [x,x_o]$ s.t. $|\cos(x)-\cos(x_o)| = |\sin(c)||x-x_o|$

Tada!

Problem here is that we are appealing to the fact $\sin(x)$ is the derivative of $\cos(x)$
...which necessarily implies that $\cos(x)$ is continuous.

Is it "good" to use MVT in proving a function is continuous?

Comment: No, you are correct. It is circular logic. But it is useful for showing that $\cos$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: @Clarinetist And Lipschitz implies continuity! Tada

Comment: Here's the thing though. Are all differentiable functions Lipschitz?

Comment: @Clarinetist Nope. $|x|\dots$

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Ah, indeed. Forgot about that one.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD that function is not differentiable everywhere....

Comment: @AlfredYerger "Here's the thing though. Are all differentiable functions Lipschitz? – Clarinetist" "@Clarinetist Nope. $|x|\dots$ YoTengoUnLCD"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you answered your own question: You're assuming what you want to prove$\dots$

Comment: @Lookbehindyou It depends on your definitions, I assume you're using the geometric definitions?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the headline question is "No."  As the OP has asserted, the MVT assumes conditions stronger than continuity.  And its use is "circular logic."

I thought it would be instructive to present a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof.

To that end, here is a ...

**HINT:**

Use the [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

$$|\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)|=2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x+x_0}{2}\right)\,\sin\left(\frac{x-x_0}{2}\right)\right| \tag 1$$

Along with the inequality

$$|\sin(x)|\le x \tag 2$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Starting from $(1)$ and using $(2)$ along with $|\sin(x)|\le 1$ reveals $$|\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)|\le |x-x_0|$$Therefore, given $\epsilon>0$, then $$|\cos(x)-\cos(x_0)|<\epsilon$$whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta =\epsilon$.  And we are done!

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, which is whether the application of the MVT is valid.

Comment: @T.Bongers It addresses the statement "I wanted to prove $f(x)=\cos(x)$ is continuous using $\epsilon-\delta$ proof."

Comment: That was the motivation for the actual question, which was "Is it "good" to use MVT in proving a function is continuous?"

Comment: @T.Bongers Sure.  I thought it would be instructive to provide an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that circumvents the circular logic. And now, let's celebrate MSU's victory over OSU today! - Mark

Comment: Why the down vote??  Would the down voter care to comment?

Comment: I didn't vote on this question, but I'd speculate that the downvote has to do with the issue I raised in my comment.

Comment: @T.Bongers A down vote is supposed to indicate that the answer is not useful.  Given the broad scope of the posted question, I don't understand how this answer is not at all useful.  It provides the coveted proof, which is what the OP is really after.  Oh well.

Comment: I think that the broad scope of the question is about whether there is a way to apply the MVT when doing such continuity proofs - not specifically about whether cosine is continuous. In that sense, I really don't see the relevance of the answer (although it would be a great answer for a different question).